# One Drive For Business sync client (OneDrive.exe) command line switches

Tags: administration, onedrive-for-business, onedrive

Does anyone know the full list of command line switches for OneDrive.exe? I've found a few here and there, but I would like to know the rest. Examples:

This would be helpful in order to automate certain tasks from a Desktop side connection to a SharePoint Library.

- `/takeover`
- `/background`
- `/configure`
- `/reset`

For Example:

When I manually sync a SharePoint folder, SharePoint automatically uses my OneDrive account to do this.

This means theoretically therefore, OneDrive should then be able to generate a sync event to the SharePoint if called from the command line (or used for a batch file to setup a user with standard SharePoint libraries, etc). . . Correct?

Alternatively, is there a method within SharePoint, (hopefully via URL or other easily adapted method invokable from a batch file / command prompt) to start the syncing?

I have also found this:
`odopen://sync?siteId=&webId=&webTitle=&listId=&listTitle=&userEmail=&listTemplateTypeId=&webUrl=&webLogoUrl=&webTemplate=&isSiteAdmin=&scope=OPENLIST`

But this is ambiguous and the source (Stack Overflow) did not have any further movement.  I will try to play with this option some more and provide an answer should this question be opened back up.

UPDATED EDIT:
Playing with the `odopen` link by itself did not work, but using `F12` in the browser (I am using Chrome), and choosing `Network` traffic allowed me to sniff out the `odopen` link being used, and from there I was able to produce (and also copy using right-click) the `odopen` link specific for the library/list needed and get it to sync - this can be called from anywhere for what it is worth.  Just be sure the link used is encoded for url.

Comment: I have also seen the switch for the next gen sync client of: /client=personal

Comment: [/shutdown](https://superuser.com/questions/741414/how-to-reset-skydrive-onedrive-sync)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: This is entirely based on [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/OfficeDocs-SharePoint/issues/2905) and as mentioned in the issue there should soon also be official documentation available.

Until then, these are the ones [@PsychoData](https://github.com/PsychoData) on GitHub was able to identify:

```
/allUsers
/background
/client= 
/configure_business
/configure_business:$tenantID
/firstSetup
/OneDrivePid:
/onPrem
/perMachineUpdate
/update
/RemoteBindToObjectWW
/remotedebug
/remoteport
/rz possibly
/shutdown
/silentConfig
/url
/url:odopen://
/wait
```